# Third normal form confused

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, third-normal-form

I have

R(ABCDE) which AB is primary key
and F= { f1: AB->CDE; f2: BD->E }

I'm confused because my textbook said it reached 3rd normal form but the when I checked it by the online tool, it said the relation reached 2rd form because of f2 violation.

Which is right?

Comment: I understand relational databases (in practice), and I understand normal forms (to some extent), but I do not understand the way you have presented your question. Can you please be more clear? What does `R(ABCDE)` mean? A 'table R' with columns ABCDE? What does `F = { f1: AB->CDE; f2: BD->E }` mean? (A 'table 'F with two fields...that...nope, I give up. I can't even guess.) Further, what "online tool" did you use to check it?

Comment: @Phrogz: It is fairly common to use a variation on the theme of `R(ABCDE)` to mean a relation R with attributes A..E, and the F is fairly clearly a set of tagged functional dependencies.  Dependency `f1` reiterates that `AB` is the primary key.  Dependency `f2` causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. Is `f2` saying that the value of `E` depends on both `B` and `D` then? (And not vice-versa?)

Comment: Yes: `f2` says the the combination of B & D functionally determines the value of E.

Comment: Third Normal Form: The key, the whole key, and nothing but the key…so help me Codd.  (Actually, that's BCNF, but the two are closely related — BCNF is more stringent than 3NF.)

Comment: It's not in 3NF because of the `f2` functional dependency.

Comment: And using the definitions for functional dependency, 2NF & 3NF, what is *your* opinion and justification?

Comment: @Phrogz But what do *you* mean by "depends on"? Look up a definition of "functional dependency".

Comment: What is the title & edition of the textbook?

Answer (score 1):

Codd's definition of 3NF includes the stipulation that every non-prime attribute of a table is non-transitively dependent on *every* key.

In other words, since E is dependent both on (AB) and (BD) but C is only dependent on (AB), this is a 3NF violation.

The online tool is right.

To make this 3NF you need to break into two relations:  ABCD and BDE.  However this poses issues relating to referential integrity enforcement.

Comment: Your justification doesn't make sense. "since E is dependent both on (AB) and (BD) but C is only dependent on (AB)" has no clear connection to "includes the stipulation that every non-prime attribute of a table is non-transitively dependent on every key". Expecting the reader to realize that AB is the only CK and that E is non-prime is not so bad, but you say nothing about E's transitive dependence on AB, and C is irrelevant. And you italicize *every* as if the relation had more than one CK, but it doesn't.